# Rider warns that if condition is always false but isn't?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, rider

I've taken code from Azure Samples repository that handles reconnections to Azure Redis Cache.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cache-redis-samples/blob/main/quickstart/dotnet-core/RedisConnection.cs

Rider reports, that the following expression is always false. How is that? Is it a Rider bug?

```
private const int RetryMaxAttempts = 5;

public async Task<T> BasicRetryAsync<T>(Func<IDatabase, Task<T>> func)
{
    var reconnectRetry = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            return await func(_database);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) when (ex is RedisConnectionException || ex is SocketException || ex is ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            reconnectRetry++;

            // here Rider warns that expression is always false
            if (reconnectRetry > RetryMaxAttempts) 
            {
                throw;
            }
```

The variable *reconnectRetry* is declared on the top.
In the loop, if there's an exception, the variable is incremented in the *catch* block and compared to constant. How this can always be false?

If I move the incrementation of *reconnectRetry* counter to *try* block, the warning goes away.

[image]

Is the *reconnectRetry* variable always 0 in the catch block? How did Rider come to this conclusion? It has to be wrong, right?

Comment: Looks like a bug in Rider.

Comment: Maybe Rider doesn't understand that the `throw` is executed conditionally and assumes the method will always be exited before `reconnectTry` gets high enough.

Comment: It does not produce such error for me (though on slightly different code). Also I would recommend to look at [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) instead of manually implementing retries.